# Jenkins Maven3 error, Artifactory is enable

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

> [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (Server/libs-release): Cannot access Server/libs-release with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access Server/libs-release using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: Unsupported transport protocol https

I have this error with Jenkins and Artifactory

Comment: Did you check the connection between your Jenkins instance to Artifactory instance?

Comment: Yes, "Found Artifactory 5.8.1" in Test Connection

Comment: Can you provide more information? From what phase you see this error. Look in your Maven log and see the last line beginning with ---:
`[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run xxxxxxxxxxxxx ---`

Comment: I solved with a multibranch pipeline, JenkinsFile and Maven2.

Comment: Also you need a virtual repository named libs-release

Comment: >The libs-release virtual repository include two repo's: A remote repository and a libs-release-local repo.